# IEnumerable and array comprehension

Tags: f#, ienumerable, list-comprehension

I wonder why the second line reports a compiler error

> the type Relations is not compatible with seq<'a>

while the first infers a type Relation for r.

```
type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database with 
    member x.f() =
        let relations =  [for r in x.Relations -> r]
        let relations2 =  x.Relations |> Seq.map id 
        ()
```

What precise property makes it possible to loop over Relations using for?

// **Edit** reproduction step :

I create a blank solution in VS2012, add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao, and paste the code below.

```
module toto = 
  type Class1() = 
      member this.X = "F#"

  type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database with 
      member x.f() =
          let relations =  [for r in x.Relations -> r]
          let relations2 =  x.Relations |> Seq.map id 
          ()
```

r is typed as Relation, and not obj

Comment: What is `x.Relations`, and are you going to do anything with `relations`? Also why `Seq.map` to itself?

Comment: x refers to an object of type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database, so x.Relations is  someting of type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822446.aspx . I Seq.map to itself only to have a small reproducible error here

Comment: Are you sure `r` isn't inferred as `obj`?

Comment: no it is correctly infered as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Relation. I think in C# Linq one has to Cast it in order to use those thoguh, which would fit your description. confirmed : in C# it is recognized as an untyped IEnumerable.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't entirely mesh with what you've said, but one scenario in which a sequence expression would work but not `Seq.map` is when a type implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` but not `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'T>` (aka `seq<'T>`). For example, in this code `t` is inferred as `obj list`, but the next line doesn't compile.

```
type T() =
  interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
    member x.GetEnumerator() = (Seq.init 10 id).GetEnumerator() :> _

let t = [for x in T() -> x]
let t2 = T() |> Seq.map id //ERROR: The type 'T' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'
```

This scenario is especially common for libraries created prior to .NET 2.0.

Comment: That must be a version of that at play. thks

Comment: ...and you fix it with `Seq.cast`.

Comment: @JoelMueller indeed, Cast<> in C# or Seq.cast in F#. what puzzled me was the difference. I guess the question is why is F# type inferer so powerful that I dont have to do it in the array comprehension case. it is magic :) but we already knew that..

Comment: @nicolas: Because `for` only depends on `IEnumerable` which provides boxed access to the current item (thus inferring the result as `obj list`).

Comment: @Daniel that is the point, the element is infered as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Relation, not obj...  I guess I'll have the occasion to encounter variation son this and removes the mystery of fsharp compiler extra sensory perception, and report here

Comment: @nicolas: I don't see that behavior. It's inferred as `obj` unless you add a type annotation.

Comment: @Daniel strange. I'll try on home computer as well.